# Qt slots and signals: Input QPushButton as a parameter?

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have this functionality:

```
void MainWindow::onJeopardySquareClicked(){
    QPushButton *temp;
    for(int i =0; i < 6;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            if(button[i][j] == sender()){
                temp = button[i][j];
                break;
        }

        }
    }
    temp->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;");
}
```

Which is connected to a grid of QPushButtons:

```
   QObject::connect(button[arrI][j],SIGNAL(pressed()),this, SLOT(onJeopardySquareClicked()));
```

Is there any ways to send the actual button so I don't need to loop through each button in the array? I don't want to subclass QPushButton if I don't have to, it seems overkill. I also want to avoid using static variables.

This is kind of what I want:

```
  void MainWindow::onJeopardySquareClicked(QPushButton clickedButton){
        clickedButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In onJeopardySquareClicked you can use [QObject::sender()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to find out from which QObject the signal originated. Otherwise you can also use a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) to map the object/widget.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the object from sender() directly, without looping? EDIT: I think map is what I want.

Comment: you would have to cast sender() to QPushButton and thus have the button that was clicked. But you can obviously also use QSignalMapper.

Answer (score 0):

sender() is ugly and non-OOP. Use QSignalMapper.

Comment: Agreed on this one. This is also mentioned in the documentation of the  function.